# MySql: Database should not accept time that overlaps the duration of other event

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating an event management system. I have some inputs taken from the user and stored in the database. Suppose there is event1 held at 8:00 and its duration is 1 hour. I must make sure there is no clashing of events, i.e I don't want to take the time of event2 as 8:30 since it clashes with event1. how do i do this?

---

ID

> id1   2012-04-16 08:00:00     event1  1    description
>
> id2   2012-04-16 08:30:00     event2  1    description

Answer (score 0):

I would store the start and end times of the event, instead of start and duration. Then you'll be able to query with WHERE new_time >= start AND new_time <= end

Alternatively, you could use the [ADD TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) function to do WHERE new_time >= start AND new_time <= ADD_TIME(start, duration)

(note, duration will have to be in a time format, as per the function specification. Also, the first method is more efficient, since you could index start and end times.